# Discord Bot always saying its online many times after being pinged by the flask server - PYTHON

Tags: python, discord, bots

Every time the flask server is pinged by UpTimeRobot, on Discord, my bot outputs it's online. I only want to say it one time, and not every time the server is pinged. How do I achieve this?

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print(f'You have logged in as {client}')
   channel = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(),name='general')

   await client.get_channel(channel.id).send('Bot is now online!')
   await client.get_channel(channel.id).send('Type $help to get more information.')
```

[Click to see what the program is doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UszRg.png)

This is not the full code

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to see more information about your code. The on_ready event is only triggered when the client connects; therefore it would seem like you are recreating the client instead of reusing an instance of the client that already exists.

Also, which type of monitor are you using from UptimeRobot? Seems like it should not be triggering your Discord bot...